# How to determine the fewest number of Y increments needed to plot a multiple of 5 on a graph?

Tags: javascript, math, charts

Using JavaScript, an array of numbers is going to be charted on a graph (for my purposes it is a [spline chart](https://c3js.org/samples/chart_spline.html)):

`[12, 22, 25, 38, 47]`

[image: spline-1]

I want all the Y axis values to be multiples of 5. I have the Y axis capped at the *next multiple of 5* that occurs after the highest number in the array. Since `47` is the highest number, the next multiple of 5 is `50` (call that value the "cap"), and that is the top value ("tick") on the chart's Y axis. After figuring that out, I know that the Y axis should be `0` a the bottom, and `50` at the top, but I want to override the default behavior and tell it exactly how many ticks to show in between, and what the values should be for those ticks.

This is where it gets tricky, because of the following restrictions:

1. Use the ***fewest*** number of ticks possible (0, the max value, and at least one tick in between)
2. Bottom value is always zero
3. All Y tick values are multiples of 5
4. Y ticks are evenly spaced on the axis

For the previous example, **fifty** is the cap, which is divisible by two, so the Y axis would only need one tick in between the bottom and top, resulting in **three** tick values of `0, 25, 50`. The function I am trying to build would receive `50` as an argument, and output `3` as the result. Then I would know the chart needs 3 ticks, and I could generate it like so:

[image: spline-2]

My question is, given that a charted value can be any multiple of 5, **how can I calculate the *fewest* number of ticks needed on the Y axis, using only increments that are multiples of 5**? It may be easiest to just show the first few scenarios to illustrate how the pattern is not (at least to me) obvious:

```
value = tick1, tick2, tick3, etc. >> return count of ticks

05 = 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 >> return 6;// This case is an outlier and can be set manually
10 = 10, 5, 0 >> return 3;
15 = 15, 10, 5, 0 >> return 4;
20 = 20, 10, 0 >> return 3;
25 = 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0 >> return 6;
30 = 30, 15, 0 >> return 3;
35 = 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0 >> return 8;
40 = 40, 20, 0 >> return 3;
45 = 45, 30, 15, 0 >> return 4;
50 = 50, 25, 0 >> return 3;
55 = 55, 50, 45, 40, 35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0 >> return 12;
```

It was at this point that I realized there is probably an equation or function that exists to address this dilemma, maybe even something to do with the Fibonacci sequence or Dan Brown. I couldn't find any related SO questions, and my use of "increments of 5" may make this use case too specific to return google results on the general principle, so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: If anyone can think of a better title, please feel free to edit

Comment: why you're `10` returns `4` and `20` returns `3`

Comment: @CodeManiac `10` and `20` would both return `3`, as in the example pseudo-code. I am looking for the fewest number of ticks to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an iterative approach by using the fifth of the value an checke the abulity for the division by 2, 3, 5, 7 and so on and return this value incremented by one.

```js
const
    fn = v => {
        v /= 5;
        if (v === 1) return 6;
        if (v % 2 === 0) return 3;
        var i = 1;
        while ((i += 2) < v) if (v % i === 0) return i + 1;
        return v + 1;
    },
    format = s => s.toString().padStart(2);

var values = Array.from({ length: 12 }, (_, i) => (i + 1) * 5),
    data = values.map(fn);

console.log(...values.map(format));
console.log(...data.map(format));
```

Comment: that returns the not covered values, like 15, 25, 35, 55, and so on, the multiples of primary numbers with five.